# ios instruments vm tracker IOKit insane residence size

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, memory, instruments

I've just been analyzing an ipad app I'm developing using Instruments. In particular I was interested in the memory usage, as I have been receiving some memory warnings.

First of all the Activity monitor reports overall some 40MB of memory used just after starting the application. This really seams like a lot to me. Especially as after the startup nothing really fancy is going on.

So I have been analyzing the app in the VM tracker.

First of all can somebody explain how to interpret the *dirty* memory? I mean the ipad doesn't  really have virtual memory, in the sense that there is no swapping etc.

Ok the really weird thing is that I have some 40 MB of *dirty* memory, that is resident! Some 38MB are listed under IOKit. Under IOKit there is no further information, what that actually means.

So what exactly does IOKit do?
What could be causing this insane those huge values?

Any kind of hint is appreciated! :)

Comment: ok it seems very likely that the memory reported by IOKit is the memory consumed by OpenGL for the textures.

Comment: Do you have a webview? This only happens to me because my webview is very large.

Comment: Nope there's no webview involved. It's mainly a OpenGL "window".

Comment: @Tobias: Hi there, did you ever solve this? I have what looks like exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try Heapshot Analysis, bbum has a great [tutorial here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17).

Basically you take a Heapshot, run some procedure, take another Heapshot for several iterations. This will help find memory that lost but not a leak. I use this method often,

I have used Heapshot many times to great advantage, many thanks to bum.

Answer (score 0):

> What is dirty memory?

According to this [session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/).

- memory written by an app
- all heap allocations
- decoded image buffers

> VM profile shows some info of the dirty memory

like dirty memory size. They are anonymous.

```
vmmap --summary App.memgraph
```

In this session, this Apple dev uses `heap` to get more info about the object sizes.

```
heap App.memgraph
```

[image]